# Entity Framework Code first error with self referencing objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to create my first EF code first objects into database. Unfortunately when trying to save my objects into DB I get this exception:

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations.
>   Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model
>   requirements, or store-generated values.

Here is the code I use to fill the DB:

```
using (var context = new MySample.Context())
{
    context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();

    CloudFile f = new CloudFile(, "file1");

    CloudDirectory d = new CloudDirectory(CloudObject.CloudContentType.Customer, "directory1");
    d.Nodes.Add(d);

    FileGroup g = new FileGroup();
    g.CloudObjects.Add(d);

    context.FileGroups.Add(g);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Actually I would like to create  an object of type `FileGroup`. This object contains either files (`CloudFile`) or directories (`CloudDirectory`). The directories can contain either other directories or files.

Here are the classes for the mentioned objects:

```
public class FileGroup {

    public FileGroup()
    {
        CloudObjects = new HashSet<CloudObject>();
    }

    public int FileGroupId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CloudObject> CloudObjects { get; set; }
}


public abstract class CloudObject {

    public CloudObject(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public int CloudObjectId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public abstract bool hasChildren { get; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Node Parent { get; set; }

    public int? FileGroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual FileGroup FileGroup { get; set; }
}

public class CloudDirectory : CloudObject {

    public CloudDirectory(string name) :base(name)
    {
        Nodes = new HashSet<CloudObject>();
    }

    public override bool hasChildren
    {
        get
        {
            return Nodes.Any();
        }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<CloudObject> Nodes { get; set; }
}

public class CloudFile : CloudObject {

    public CloudFile(string name) : base(name)
    {
    }

    public string ETag { get; set; }

    public override bool hasChildren
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what I need to change in my objects so that they can be stored successfully do DB?

Comment: What is `Node` here `public virtual Node Parent { get; set; }`?

Answer (score 1):

Several changes in your test code (the code comments explain them):

```
using (var context = new MySample.Context())
{
    context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();

    CloudFile f = new CloudFile("file1");

    CloudDirectory d = new CloudDirectory("directory1");

    //This seems to be wrong:
    //d.Nodes.Add(d);
    d.Nodes.Add(f); //I guess you don't want d to be its own parent, but want it to be f's parent

    FileGroup g = new FileGroup();
    g.CloudObjects.Add(d);
    //Another way to do it:
    //d.FileGroup = g;

    //You also want f to be in the FileGroup, you have to add it explicitly
    g.CloudObjects.Add(f);
    //Another way to do it: 
    //f.FileGroup = g;

    context.FileGroups.Add(g);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

As the relationships between the entities are a bit too complex for EF automatic conventions to deal with them, you should add explicit mappings for them in your `DbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<CloudObject>().HasOptional(x => x.Parent).WithMany(x => x.Nodes).HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<CloudObject>().HasOptional(x => x.FileGroup).WithMany(x => x.CloudObjects).HasForeignKey(x => x.FileGroupId);
}
```

Note: I assumed here that `FileGroup` is not mandatory for a given `CloudObject`. If it is mandatory you should change the method `HasOptional` to `HasRequired`.

You should also change the type of this property:

```
public abstract class CloudObject
{
    ...
    //public virtual Node Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual CloudDirectory Parent { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Your migration has to look somewhat like this:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.CloudObjects",
        c => new
            {
                CloudObjectId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Name = c.String(),
                ParentId = c.Int(),
                FileGroupId = c.Int(),
                ETag = c.String(),
                Discriminator = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.CloudObjectId)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.FileGroups", t => t.FileGroupId)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.CloudObjects", t => t.ParentId)
        .Index(t => t.ParentId)
        .Index(t => t.FileGroupId);

 CreateTable(
    "dbo.FileGroups",
        c => new
            {
                FileGroupId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Name = c.String(),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.FileGroupId);
```